# Adding constant class after event occurred

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How can I add a class to element not if condition is true,

```
<div ng-class="{myClass: true/false}">
```

but if event is occurred. For example I have td, which displays some variable.

```
<td>{{myVar}}</td>//myVar=10
```

And when variable changed `myVar=15` I add a constant class to div, which(class) don't depends on condition any more. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your angular controller. Note that i'm selecting all divs in HTML using querySelector while you should select the div as per your requirement

```
$scope.$watch('myVar', function() {
    var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('div'));
        myEl.addClass('myClass');
}, true);
```